# How to get awk command to work in Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have bash script that takes user input an store them in variables! I use an awk command to search for some patterns in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter Data"
echo "Enter first pattern"
read firstpat

echo "Enter number"
read num1

echo "Enter name"
read name1

echo "Enter second pattern"
read secpat

echo "Enter second number"
read num2

echo "Enter name
read name2

awk '$0 >= "$firstpat $num1:$name1" && $0 <= "$secpat $num2:$name2"' /dir1/file1
```

Everything in the script works fine, but the awk command does not show any result. If I run the same awk command in terminal without variables instead of a file it works!

Comment: That command is simply wrong in that it's trying to access shell variables inside an awk script, it will NOT work in a terminal any better than it works in a file. If you are running a command that works in your terminal, it is not THAT command. awk is not shell, see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.

Comment: @EdMorton in terminal in run without variables!

Comment: So then it's obviously not the same command so why say it is? Adding red herrings like that just makes your question confusing. [edit] your question to simply state the truth with no misdirection that'd make it harder for people to figure out what problem you're having and help you to fix it. "Why does Command X works while Command Y doesn't?" is a very different question from "Why does Command Y work in environment A but not in environment B?".

Comment: @EdMorton I have edited my question!

Comment: [edit] your question to replace the word "pattern" (or "pat") with either "regexp" or "string", whichever it is you want to match on, as the word "pattern" is ambiguous and its use in requirements usually leads to scripts that initially work for some input and then later fail spectacularly for other input. Also add concise, testable sample input and expected output (i.e. a [mcve]) so we can see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` you have to define shell variable again for `awk` script. You can use variable name same as in your shell script.

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -v "firstpat=$firstpat" -v "num1=$num1" -v "name1=$name1" -v "secpat=$secpat" -v "num2=$num2" -v "name2=$name2"  '$0 >= "$firstpat $num1:$name1" && $0 <= "$secpat $num2:$name2"' /dir1/file1
```

Comment: No you can't (hints: no `$` to get awk variables contents and `"..."` is a string) and you aren't defining shell variables again, you're defining awk variables and initializing them with the value of shell variables. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.